# Extract and match sets from list of filenames

Tags: r, sorting, filtering

I have a dataset of 4000+ images. For the purpose of figuring out the code, I moved a small subset of them to another folder.

The files look like this:

folder

```
[1] "r01c01f01p01-ch3.tiff" "r01c01f01p01-ch4.tiff" "r01c01f02p01-ch1.tiff"
[4] "r01c01f03p01-ch2.tiff" "r01c01f03p01-ch3.tiff" "r01c01f04p01-ch2.tiff"
[7] "r01c01f04p01-ch4.tiff" "r01c01f05p01-ch1.tiff" "r01c01f05p01-ch2.tiff"
[10] "r01c01f06p01-ch2.tiff" "r01c01f06p01-ch4.tiff" "r01c01f09p01-ch3.tiff"
[13] "r01c01f09p01-ch4.tiff" "r01c01f10p01-ch1.tiff" "r01c01f10p01-ch4.tiff"
[16] "r01c01f11p01-ch1.tiff" "r01c01f11p01-ch2.tiff" "r01c01f11p01-ch3.tiff"
[19] "r01c01f11p01-ch4.tiff" "r01c02f10p01-ch1.tiff" "r01c02f10p01-ch2.tiff"
[22] "r01c02f10p01-ch3.tiff" "r01c02f10p01-ch4.tiff"
```

I cannot remove the name prior to the -ch# as that information is important. What I want to do, however, is to filter this list of images, and return only sets (ie: r01c02f10p01) which have all four ch values (ch1-4).

I was originally thinking that we could approach the issue along the lines of this:

```
ch1 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp/complete//", pattern="ch1")
ch2 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp/complete//", pattern="ch2")
ch3 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp/complete//", pattern="ch3")
ch4 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp/complete//", pattern="ch4")
```

Applying this list with the `file.remove` function, similar to this:

```
final2 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp1/Images//", pattern="ch5") 
file.remove(folder,final2)
```

However, creating new variables for each ch value fragments out each file. I am unsure how to use these to actually distinguish whether an individual image has all four ch values to meaningfully filter my images. I'm kind of at a loss, as the other sources I've seen have issues that don't quite match this problem.

Earlier, I was able to remove the all images with ch5 from my image set like this. I was thinking this may be helpful in trying to filter only images which have ch1-ch4, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
##Create folder variable which has all image files 
folder <- list.files(getwd())

##Create final2 variable which has all image files ending in ch5
final2 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp1/Images//", pattern="ch5") 

##Remove final2 from folder
file.remove(folder,final2)
```

To summarize: I expect to filter files from a random assortment without complete ch values (ie: maybe only ch1 and ch2, or ch3 and ch4, or ch1, ch2, ch3, and ch4), to an assortment which only contains files which have a complete set (four files with ch1, ch2, ch3, and ch4).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a vector of filenames like you would get from `list.files` or something similar, you can create a data frame of filenames, use regex to extract the alphanumeric part at the beginning and the number that follows `"-ch"`. Then check that all elements of an expected set (I put this in `ch_set`, but there might be another way you need to do this) occur in each group's set of CH values.

```r
# assume this is the vector of file names that comes from list.files
# or something comparable
files <- c("r01c01f01p01-ch3.tiff", "r01c01f01p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f02p01-ch1.tiff", "r01c01f03p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c01f03p01-ch3.tiff", "r01c01f04p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c01f04p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f05p01-ch1.tiff", "r01c01f05p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c01f06p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c01f06p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f09p01-ch3.tiff", "r01c01f09p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f10p01-ch1.tiff", "r01c01f10p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f11p01-ch1.tiff", "r01c01f11p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c01f11p01-ch3.tiff", "r01c01f11p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c02f10p01-ch1.tiff", "r01c02f10p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c02f10p01-ch3.tiff", "r01c02f10p01-ch4.tiff")

library(dplyr)

ch_set <- 1:4

files_to_keep <- data.frame(filename = files, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  tidyr::extract(filename, into = c("group", "ch"), regex = "(^[\\w\\d]+)\\-ch(\\d)", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(ch = as.numeric(ch)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(all(ch_set %in% ch))

files_to_keep
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>   filename              group           ch
#>   <chr>                 <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 r01c01f11p01-ch1.tiff r01c01f11p01     1
#> 2 r01c01f11p01-ch2.tiff r01c01f11p01     2
#> 3 r01c01f11p01-ch3.tiff r01c01f11p01     3
#> 4 r01c01f11p01-ch4.tiff r01c01f11p01     4
#> 5 r01c02f10p01-ch1.tiff r01c02f10p01     1
#> 6 r01c02f10p01-ch2.tiff r01c02f10p01     2
#> 7 r01c02f10p01-ch3.tiff r01c02f10p01     3
#> 8 r01c02f10p01-ch4.tiff r01c02f10p01     4
```

Now that you have a dataframe of the complete groups, just pull the matching filenames back out:

```r
files_to_keep$filename
#> [1] "r01c01f11p01-ch1.tiff" "r01c01f11p01-ch2.tiff" "r01c01f11p01-ch3.tiff"
#> [4] "r01c01f11p01-ch4.tiff" "r01c02f10p01-ch1.tiff" "r01c02f10p01-ch2.tiff"
#> [7] "r01c02f10p01-ch3.tiff" "r01c02f10p01-ch4.tiff"
```

One thing to note is that this worked without the `mutate` line where I converted `ch` to numeric—i.e. comparing character versions of those numbers to regular numeric version of them—because under the hood, `%in%` converts to matching types. That didn't seem totally safe if you needed to scale this, so I converted to have them in matching types.

Comment: If I am trying to scale this to 4000+ images, I'm going to have difficulty creating a list of the files as you have in the first step. Could we not just achieve the same by using a variable called "folder" which has all of them? Or does that miss a conversion between variable types to use them in the rest of the code?

Comment: If you mean the variable `files`, I had to do that because you didn't include a workable sample of the filenames you were using. I made the vector by cleaning the printout text you included. It seems like you're getting something comparable by calling `list.files`, but without access to your list of files, I mimicked it this way. Replace that with however you're getting your list of files.

Comment: Using the list.files command is exactly how I got everything to work in the first place, and I think I follow you. The issue I'm now having is actually observing the changes the code should write. My original folder is not reflecting changes, and when I try     final <- files_to_keep$filename,   then    file.create(final, dir(path="/Desktop/Nov5_1//"))  to write them to a new folder, that is also not working.

Comment: Not working how? And what do you mean that the original folder is not reflecting changes? I didn't include any manipulation of actual files, since your question was about figuring out what the appropriate files are

Comment: @Wysteria doing bulk file creation/deletion/moving seems like a separate task from just extracting and counting parts of filenames. Maybe post that as a separate question

Comment: Based on the way I had coded it in the first place, I thought the tasks were interchangeable without writing the files as a data frame.  I'll repost. Thanks!